# How to configure Paypal for multitenancy?

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, multi-tenant

I'm coding a multi-tenant application using Laravel where final user can buy stuff from a tenant and pay with Paypal.

How can i allow the tenant to receive payments knowing only its Paypal email account?

Or what Paypal information would the tenant need to provide to our application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal does not offer multi-tenancy, at least for now.

Take a look at [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/), a subsidiary of PayPal (Works now only in US).

Also [MangoPay](https://www.mangopay.com/) is a great alternative with a good API. For sure there are yet other payment systems currently on the market offering multi-tenancy feature.